# "Einstein showed that everything is relative."?

Tags: relativity

Is this statement accurate? I've been sitting on this for a bit and cannot come to terms with my thoughts, so I need insight on this statement, from both a Physics and/or Philosophical perspective.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Exchange. "Everything" is not relative in physical terms - and it's not what Einstein meant (if he ever said this). If you want to talk about everything, you have also left physics and the scope of this site by quite a bit. What you can talk about is what is relative about the theory of relativity. It boils down to the assumption that the physical laws look the same in all systems of inertia and there is not "the" system of inertia. That's all that is meant by "relative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Philosophically, no, it is not accurate.

What Einstein showed was that certain physical properties — length, mass, and time — vary according to one's reference frame, and are thus “relative” to the motion of the observer.

In my experience, when people say “everything is relative” they're suggesting that there is an arbitrariness to things which is completely inaccurate.

Einstein created two theories of relativity, the first was special relativity, published in 1905, which shows how to translate measurements performed by one observer in one reference frame to another observer in another reference frame, but only reference frames moving at constant velocities — no acceleration allowed.

His motivation was actually a property of the equations for electromagnetism, which indicates that regardless of how fast or slow one travels, one will always measure light to travel at the exact same speed, meaning the speed of light doesn't vary with the speed of the observer, or is invariant. (By the 1880s experimenters were beginning to confirm this experimentally.)

In 1915 he published his general theory of relativity, which extended these ideas to reference frames undergoing accelerations, including accelerations due to gravity.

But at no point did he show that “everything is relative,” and in fact his theories did quite the opposite, providing methods to exactly translate measurements between observers in a reproducible and exact way.